# Dealing with downtime in a microservices deployment

Tags: rest, microservices

Company is new with microservices.  Conceptually, it makes a lot of sense, and really describes SaaS applications as the true enterprise grade apps that they're meant to be.  I've had applications talking to REST APIs for a long while, so it seems like a good fit.

However, there are concerns with downtime.  Specifically, a service is under maintenance, how resilient should producers of data for that service be?  It takes 30 minutes to do an upgrade (let's say), do we fail transactions for those 30 minutes? Do we simply apply circuit breakers, and say that there's some backing mechanism for the failure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Microservices and "down for maintenance" deployments are not generally practiced together. You would deploy microservices in the context of cluster orchestration and fault-tolerant load balancing.

Service *gamma* needs to serve 300 requests per second. Your load testing and capacity planning exercise tells you this means it needs, at minimum, 5 instances. Consequently, you instruct your cluster scheduler to run 7, so you can tolerate 2 failures.

Service *delta* depends on *gamma*.

You want to upgrade *gamma*. You instruct the build system to create a build of *gamma-2.0* while keeping *gamma-1.0* around.

You then instruct the cluster scheduler to upgrade *gamma* to *gamma-2.0*. *One at a time*, it stops an instance of *gamma-1.0* and spins up *gamma-2.0* in its place. It might hard-stop the old process, letting requests to it be retried behind the scenes (statistically, they should hit an alive instance before too many retries). Or it might remove the targeted instance from the load balancer, give it some time to "drain" what it's already working on (possibly including sending it a signal through the OS), kill it, spin up a *gamma-2.0* process, health-check the new *gamma-2.0* process, and the finally add the address of the new *gamma-2.0* process to the load balancer. Repeat until all *gamma-1.0* processes are dead and replaced with *gamma-2.0*.

For very large deployments you might act on more than one instance at a time. The important thing is that during a deploy, there are always enough alive instances of the service being deployed to meet the *service level objective* for dealing with incoming traffic in a timely and correct manner. You'd want to plan for "shit happens" failures to coincide with a deployment, which is why I said tolerate 2 failures and not 1. The instance being upgraded at a given moment is "failed" and some other failure could happen at the same time.

During this process, you would watch your dashboards, alerts, and error log aggregation of *gamma* for any irregularities. If you see an unacceptable increase in latency or error rate correlated with the rollout percentage of *gamma-2.0*, then you (or an automated system) might instruct the cluster scheduler to *rollback*. The cluster scheduler might also decide to *rollback* if some percentage of *gamma-2.0* instances fail a health check (i.e. can't respond to "hey are you alive" or just exit immediately).

A rollback runs the same process, replacing *gamma-2.0* instances with *gamma-1.0* instances.

The result is that, from *delta*'s perspective, *gamma* is always alive. If someone deploys a bad change to *gamma*, than some percentage of *delta*'s requests are problematic, but only for a little while.

This has some interesting consequences. For example, you don't get to make breaking API changes in one shot: you're going to have mutually incompatible versions running side-by-side. You might add a new endpoint in *gamma*, start using it in *delta*, and then finally remove the old endpoint in *gamma* with 3 separate deploys. You can avoid this by (correctly) using an RPC framework with support for backwards-compatible changes (Thrift, gRPC, etc). So, for example, you add an optional field to the end of a response from *gamma-2.0*. *delta-1.0*'s Thrift decoder won't know what it's about, and just silently drop it and function as before. *delta-2.0* will interpret and use it correctly. If *gamma* is ever rolled back to 1.0, *delta-2.0* is still required to function correctly in the absence of the field, because it's marked optional.

You can also do blue-green deployments. Let's say you're running *gamma-1.0* on the blue side. You build up 7 *gamma-2.0* instances on the green side, and validate that they're functioning properly. Then you instruct the load balancer to shift traffic over to the green side. Once the blue side is dark (no traffic) you're free to reuse it for the next deployment. Downside is, you need a smarter load balancing layer, and 2x the hardware capacity.

Real-world cluster schedulers with this kind of functionality include Mesos with Aurora, Mesos with Marathon, and Kubernetes.

Services *can* still go down. For example, if the new *gamma* deploy is bad but no one figures out to rollback, *delta*'s requests may all fail. Say *delta* retries each failed requests 3 times. Delta's upstream consumer *lambda* may interpret these errors from *delta* as cause to retry 3 times. Soon you've got 9x the usual traffic to *gamma*. Even if you fix the problem and deploy a correct *gamma-3.0*, *gamma-3.0* probably can't stay alive under 9x the load it was designed for. This is why we use the circuit breaker pattern.

Comment: You can _exponential backoff_, where retry loops include increasing sleep(n) calls between attempts. Eventually all threads that could storm gamma with requests are busy sleeping. You can also rate limit delta's outbound calls, where you set an upper bound on the request volume from delta to gamma. You can make failures from gamma temporarily lower the rate limit, such that a ton of failures in a short time "use up" the rate limit and make it 0, essentially an open circuit breaker. This approach is called _backpressure_. These deal with partial degradation nicely; circuits are all or nothing.

Comment: Ok, this makes a lot of sense, great explanation.  So now, if that far end is an actual UI, am I actually blocking them from doing work if my downstream dependency is unavailable?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you consider blue-green deployment for microservices. Refer https://technologyconversations.com/2016/02/08/blue-green-deployment/ . In our case, we use AWS CodeDeploy which supports blue-green deployments.